# Not able to receive messages from other people using web socket on server

Tags: websocket, ratchet

Hi i am using ratchet server it's working fine when i login on same system on 2 different browser but when i login on different system it not able to receive msg from other system but i can send msg but. please help if anyone can pleas.

Comment: maybe next system has not Prerequisite

Comment: install jdk on next system or .net

Comment: i am using php so why i need install .net and also i have jdk.